# VS Tools for Cordova - can I use Phonegap build service?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

As a windows only user, what are my options for building a IOS app with VS Tools for Cordova plugin?

I've built a nice killer app, but only able to run it on android. I looked at Phonegap build, but I seems to be some inconsistent with the plugin namespace. This is what I did.

- Copied the www directory to a new github project
- Copied the config.xml file into the same project
- Built using phonegap build service

Result, a running ios app without plugins.

I noticed the vs: prefix in config.xml, so I tried replace with the gap: prefix, but then got errors about unsupported plugins.

Question is: Will I be able to build my project for IOS without buying a mac?

Comment: Hi Larsi, it is Very unlikely that you can do that without buying a mac, I tried it for more than 30 hours!  if you have a spare pc running Windows 7 with i3 cpu or above, you may try to install the osx 10.x.x in the pc.  during the install, it is Very likely that you will encounter the following problem:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually several options.  One is to use a service like MacInCloud. There are instructions on using it with VS here: "[Build and Simulate iOS in the Cloud](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn858446.aspx)".

The advantage you have here is you'd be able to use the "Application Loader" to publish your app, Xcode itself, or the iOS Simulator. It's a full Mac replacement rather than just the build. You can rent by the hour, month, or get dedicated capacity and the "vs-mda-remote" agent is pre-installed.

Here is a tutorial on converting a Cordova project to a PhoneGap Build project:  "[Build and Simulate iOS in the Cloud](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn859242.aspx)".

Unfortunately PhoneGap Build does not fully support Cordova or even PhoneGap CLI "local" projects (which are essentially Cordova CLI projects) - a number of features are missing such as hooks support, custom plugins.